# How can I find and replace two different strings in multiple filenames within a directory?

Tags: python

I have a folder: `C:\Images\Thumbnails`

that contains multiple folders:

```
180510-Image Export
180514-Image Export
180517-Image Export
180521-Image Export
```

That each contain two tif files:

```
Image Export_c1.tif
Image Export_c2.tif
```

I need to replace c1 with c01 and c2 with c02 for all `.tif` files, keeping them in their subfolders in C:\Images\Thumbnails using python

Thanks!

Comment: did you try looking up how to rename files in python?

Comment: [Glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) is a nice library for scanning a directory. You can use `glob.glob('*/*.tif')` to get a list of all the files absolute paths, then work from there to rename them

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

for r, d, files in os.walk('C:/Images/Thumbnails') :  # put your directory here
    for f in files :
        if not f.endswith( '.tif') : continue  # ignore non '.tif' files
        new_file = f.replace('c1', 'c01').replace('c2', 'c02')
        if new file != f :
            os.rename( os.path.join(r,file), os.path.join(r, new_file) )
```